# iOS enterFullScreen for HTML5 video using onloadedmetadata inconsistent results

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, html, video

I'm working with some HTML5 video where I have a custom play button set up. On desktop/non-touch devices this all works fine but what I want to do is on touch devices, enable fullscreen (it does this by default on iOS phone but not iOS tablet) which I force after I have been given the go ahead by the `onloadedmetadata` function. I'm having one issue, however. Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. I have logging 'loaded' to the console once it's been given the go ahead to check it's getting that far and it always logs but then I am thrown the error `InvalidStateError (DOM Exception 11): The object is in an invalid state.` for `webkitEnterFullScreen`.

Any ideas? Code included below.

```
function startFullscreen(elem) {
    if (elem.enterFullScreen) {
        elem.enterFullScreen();
    } else if (elem.mozEnterFullScreen) {
        elem.mozEnterFullScreen();
    } else if (elem.webkitEnterFullScreen) {
        elem.webkitEnterFullScreen();
    } else if (elem.msEnterFullScreen) {
        elem.msEnterFullScreen();
    }
}

$('.media a.video__trigger').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this),
    $parent = $this.parent('.media'),
    $video = $parent.find('video'),
    video = $parent.find('video').get(0),
    videoSource = $video.find('source'),
    webm = $this.data('video-webm'),
    mp4 = $this.data('video-mp4');
    videoSource[0].src = webm; // WebM is first
    videoSource[1].src = mp4; // MP4 is second
    if (supportsTouch) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            video.load();
            video.onloadedmetadata = function() {
                console.log('loaded');
                startFullscreen(video);
                video.play();
            };
        }, 250);
    } else {
        video.load();
        video.play();
    }
});
```